# C# jagged array of int and array

Tags: c#

I can't find out how to do the following array:

```
{ 3, 5, 15, { 4, 75, { 25 } } }
```

It must be mix of Int and Array.
My code for the function is as follows:

```
p.myMethod(new int[]{ 3, 5, 15, new int[] { 4, 75, new int []{ 25 } } })
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I get my expected result?

Comment: Why "doesn't it work"? What is the output you get?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you showed us `myMethod` and explained why you think “It must be mix of Int and Array”.

Comment: What you have shown is not jagged array.you have some series of nested arrays. are you sure what you want is actually that?

Comment: The function must pass any Int or nested Array. For example - myMetod(15); or my Metod ({15,2,{3,2,{5}}}). And it out them sum, if value devide only five. Code is excute, but myMethod can't pass a nested array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

```
{ 3, 5, 15, { 4, 75, { 25 } } }
```

items at index 0, 1, 2 are integers. item at index 4 is another type like this:

```
{ 4, 75, { 25 } }
```

Arrays cannot have multiple types in them. When you create an array you have to specify the type it will contain.

Therefore, the only array type you can keep all of the above will be an array of type `object` since everything in .NET derive from `object`.

Like this:

```
var a = new object[] { 3, 5, 15, new object[] { 4, 75, new[] { 25 } } };
```

Or you an use `ArrayList`:

```
var a = new ArrayList { 3, 5, 15, new ArrayList() { 4, 75, new ArrayList() { 25 } } };
```

Answer (score 0):

> It must be mix of Int and Array

The only way to have an array contain **multiple types of objects** would be to declare and initialize the arrays with the type of a base class of **all** of the elements, so in this case you would have to use `object`:

```
object[] array = new object[]{ 3, 5, 15, new object[] { 4, 75, new object []{ 25 } } };
```

The problem with this is obviously that you'll need to know the type of each array entry when accessing them later on because they are all declared as `object`.